# Binding a twisted matrix remote call to a ttk button results in the remote call running on client launch

Tags: python, button, twisted, snmp, ttk

Im using python and twisted to write a snmp management program, part of it requires some buttons on the client side to be bound to a remote snmp set method, this is being handled with a perspective broker.

```
for item in devicevars[current+" buttons"]:
    ttk.Label(buttonframe, text=item + ":").grid(column=1, row=i2, sticky=(E))
    ttk.Button(buttonframe,width = 3,textvariable=guivars["%s %s" %(current, 
                                item)],command=remoteButton(current, item)).grid(column=2, row=i2, sticky=(W))
    i2 = i2+1


def remoteButton(dname, value):

    rbutton= pbfactory.getRootObject()
    rbutton.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("SNMP", dname, value))
    rbutton.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
```

The problem is that this code causes the remote method to fire off as soon as the client launches. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `command` option in `Tkinter` (and therefore also `ttk`) is a callable object that will be invoked when the button is clicked.

By passing `command=remoteButton(...)` you are calling `remoteButton` immediately and then passing its result as the `command` option.

What you want to do, instead, is pass a `command` option that, when run, will call `remoteButton`.

The way to do this is:

```
ttk.Button(buttonframe,width = 3,
           textvariable=guivars["%s %s" %(current, item)],
           command=lambda: remoteButton(current, item))
```

In other words, stick a `lambda:` in front of it and you will get a function that calls it instead of just calling it.